# Tools to support Android native code hacking?

Tags: android, injection

I am learning android reverse engineering, and want to know tools to hack native code.

- gdb to remotely debug the code, but I find it can not ever hit a breakpoint.
- [arminject](https://github.com/evilsocket/arminject) is a choice, it works on ARM, and has some issues.
- IDA is great and too expensive for me.

Any more suggestions?